# Outlook AddIn with vue.js - Issue accessing Office object

Tags: vue.js, office-js

New to vue.js and having an issue accessing the Office object within Vue methods.

As you can see below calling load() from created works fine, however, calling it from this.loadProps() doesn't.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    subject: "",
  },
  created: function () {
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
      var element = document.querySelector('.ms-MessageBanner');
      messageBanner = new fabric.MessageBanner(element);
      messageBanner.hideBanner();

      //this works
      load();
    };
    //this doesn't
    //this.loadProps();
  },
  methods: {
    loadProps: function () {
      load();
    }
  }
});
function load() {
  var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
  vm.subject = item.subject;
}
```

I am loading my scripts into the HTML like so

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/vue.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/FabricUI/MessageBanner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="MessageRead.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Appreciate any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Silly mistake.

The Office object wasn't fully initialised the calling this.loadProps(). If I call vm.loadProps() in place of load(). It works fine.

Is is bad practice with Vue.js to have methods outside of the vm?

Comment: Yes, I think having methods outside it bad practice.